# Usb to ethernet converter for Rspberry pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, usb, ethernet-port

I am having a raspberry pi3 model b v1.2. The ethernet port available in the board is connected to modem.
I just need one more ethernet port so i have decided to buy a usb to ethernet converter.

What factors have to be considered while go for usb to ethernet converter?

Whether they require any driver software or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this list for which USB Ethernet adaptors work with the Pis: http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Ethernet_adapters

From my own experience I can only emphasize the advice given in the official Raspberry Foundation forum to **strictly avoid any Davicom-based USB Ethernet adaptors** at all. I've spent several hours trying to hunt down all kind of network problems until I finally replaced several Davicom adaptors with Sitecom model LN-030 v3.001 adaptors (Realtek-based). The Davicoms only appear to work, but most of the time they don't. And I had four of them, all with the same issues. In contrast, the Sitecoms work without issues, even if they only feature Realtek chips.

Avoid any USB Ethernet adaptors that don't work out of the box with a stock Linux kernel. Some adaptors boast Linux drivers, some don't even have them as they're for Windows only. Most of the time, such drivers that were never integrated into the mainline kernel have severe issues, don't compile, or only in specific environments depending on sunshine hours, moon phase, and other parameters. Save the troubles, and vote with your wallet for those USB Ethernet adaptors that work right out of the (Pi) box.

Comment: Once we have selected a adapter what will be the next step. We only need to change the file /etc/network/interfaces with "iface eth1 inet manual". Am i right?

Comment: Or they require any additional drivers?

Comment: Your /etc/network/interfaces should contain the necessary clauses for handling eth1. Settings depend on what you intend to achieve with the second wired interface.

Comment: I have purchased Trendnet TU2-ET100 adapter. Can you please help me to configure the raspberry pi.

Comment: I found this @ http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Ethernet_adapters. They given that it work out of box. I think it works in my Rapberry Pi, will they? Can you please tell me

Comment: Plug the Ethernet USB adapter into the Raspberry Pi. After some seconds, check with `ifcpnfig` eth1 that the adapter has been found and works. How to further proceed depends on which fuction you want the Pi to perform network-wise. There are many answers here on that topic.

Comment: yeah i will try to do that. Do you mean ifconfig?. Actually i have booked the adapter and i haven't received yet. Please stay touch in this question. Thank you

Comment: Sir TheDiveO, the purpose usb to ethernet converter is to provide internet to repeaters. That is in built ethernet port in raspberry pi will act as input from the router and other one is used to serve internet to the repeaters.

Comment: 1. yes, I meant `ipconfig` (typing on a mobile phone...). 2. what you merely describe as a "repeater" can be either A) a (NAT) router, or B) a bridge. In both cases, you can find a lot of receipes on how to configure Raspberry Pis as NAT routers or bridges. Often, the receipes go along the line of `eth0`+`wlan0`, but you can easily use them for `eth0`+`eth1` by just leaving out the `wlan0` access point (AP) configuration and replacing `wlan0` by `eth1`.